# Laravel using Ajax Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to update my form using AJAX POST method in Laravel, while submitting the form I am getting error:

> Creating default object from empty value

I have tried this code to accomplish my goal.

**Here is my Ajax call**:

```
        $('.submit').click(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                });
            var form = $('form')[0];
            var update = new FormData(form);
            var id =$('.designNo').val();
         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
              url:"/design_update/"+id,
                processData: false,  // Important!
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
              data:update,
              success:function(results){
                if (results==1) {
                    $("#result").html("Upadated Successfully");
                    $('#result')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
                    $("#result").addClass("alert alert-success"); 
                      window.setTimeout(function(){
                      window.location.href = "/design";
                      }, 2000);
                  }else{
                    $('#error').html(results);
                    $('#error')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
                    $('#error').addClass("alert alert-danger");
                    }
                }
            }); 
        });
```

and this is what I have done in Laravel Controller to accomplish my goal.

**Here is my Laravel Controller page :**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // To Update
    // $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    $this->validate($request,[
        'design_no'=>'required',
        'design_image'=>'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);
            // Handle file Upload
     if ($request->hasFile('design_image')) {
        // Get filename with image 
            $filenameWithex=$request->file('design_image');
        // Get just file name
             $filename=$_FILES['design_image']['name'];
            // $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithex,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ex 
            // $extension=pathinfo($filenameWithex,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // File Name To Store
            $fileNameToStore=$filename;
        // Upload Image
            $path=$request->file('design_image')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);
    }else{
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }
    $design=design::find($id);
    $design->design_no=$request->input('design_no');
    $design->desg_1=$request->input('desg_1');
    $design->design_image=$fileNameToStore;
    $design->desg_2=$request->input('desg_2');
    $design->desg_3=$request->input('desg_3');
    $design->desg_4=$request->input('desg_4');
    $design->desg_5=$request->input('desg_5');
    $design->desg_6=$request->input('desg_6');    
    $design->save();
    return '1';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here in `$design=design::find($id);`

I think `$design` has null in words `$design=design::find($id);` is returning null here??

if so you need to put a check

```
$design=design::find($id);
    if($design){
            $design->desg_1=$request->input('desg_1');
            $design->design_image=$fileNameToStore;
            $design->desg_2=$request->input('desg_2');
            $design->desg_3=$request->input('desg_3');
            $design->desg_4=$request->input('desg_4');
            $design->desg_5=$request->input('desg_5');
            $design->desg_6=$request->input('desg_6'); 
    }
```

If you want to update your record then I would suggest the simple update query approach for you like this way

```
design::where('design_no',$id)->update([
           'desg_1' => $request->input('desg_1'),
            'design_image'=> $fileNameToStore,
            'desg_2' => $request->input('desg_2'),
            'desg_3' => $request->input('desg_3'),
            'desg_4' => $request->input('desg_4'),
            'desg_5' => $request->input('desg_5'),
            'desg_6' => $request->input('desg_6') 
]);
```

Hope this will fix your issue :)

Comment: When i analysis  network design no passing correctly  like below
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="design_no" 6

Comment: yes its not entering when deleted it and recode (In find any spl char )its entering and throwing error like this: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5' for key 'designs_design_no_unique'

Comment: you are getting this error because you already have a record in your table where design_design_no_unique =5 I assume

Comment: check my updated answer use update query for updating records :)

Comment: Its throwing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'

Comment: if i use , insted of ;  ie( $design->desg_2=$request->input('desg_2'),
            $design->desg_3=$request->input('desg_3'),)
like this also it throw error (Creating default object from empty value)

Comment: hey I am really sorry I created the mess here now I have updated and solved my mess you can use 2nd one approach for you

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr.Pyramid

Comment: pleasure bro :)

Comment: One more query :While update if i didn't change file the file upload always fails in if condition how could i  resolve it

Comment: file name means those input values like desg_1 etc?

Comment: design_image  where the file name get uploded ,Iam checking for hasfile in if condition it going always false so noimage got updated if i didn't update the file

Comment: please post as a question I will answer you there as I need to see your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557915/errorwhile-updating-form-using-ajax-post-method-in-laravel