# Error:While updating form Using Ajax Post method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to update my Laravel form While updating other fields except `file` field the Laravel  I am checking this using `hasfile()` it's getting failed.

If I update the file upload the condition works perfectly the only problem occur while I am updating the other form field without updating the file

**Here my Controller Page:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'design_no'=>'required',
        'design_image'=>'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);
            // Handle file Upload
     if ($request->hasFile('design_image')) {
        // Get filename with image 
            $filenameWithex=$request->file('design_image');
        // Get just file name
             $filename=$_FILES['design_image']['name'];
            // $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithex,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ex 
            // $extension=pathinfo($filenameWithex,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // File Name To Store
            $fileNameToStore=$filename;
            $path=$request->file('design_image')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);
    }else{
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }
design::where('design_no',$id)->update([
           'desg_1' => $request->input('desg_1'),
            'design_image'=> $fileNameToStore,
            'desg_2' => $request->input('desg_2'),
            'desg_3' => $request->input('desg_3'),
            'desg_4' => $request->input('desg_4'),
            'desg_5' => $request->input('desg_5'),
            'desg_6' => $request->input('desg_6') 
]);
    $design->save();
    return '1';
}
```

Here is my Ajax call:

```
    $('.submit').click(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
            });
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var update = new FormData(form);
        var id =$('.designNo').val();
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
          url:"/design_update/"+id,
            processData: false,  // Important!
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
          data:update,
          success:function(results){
            if (results==1) {
                $("#result").html("Upadated Successfully");
              }else{
                $('#error').html(results);
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: What's inside `$request->all()`?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @aldrin27 i coudn't understand

Comment: What i mean is what's the value of `$request` variable.

Comment: did you got the solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to validate your file like this

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'design_no'=>'required',
        'design_image'=>'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:1999'
    ]);
```

Then you need to fetch the record that you are updating if you already have those record then ignore this step.

```
$designData = design::where('design_no',$id)->first();
```

Now you need to put a check on you variable `$fileNameToStore` if it has `noImage.jpg` means you are not updating image here in that case you need to update keep your last uploaded file intact else update your image file like this.

```
design::where('design_no',$id)->update([
           'desg_1' => $request->input('desg_1'),
            'design_image'=> ($fileNameToStore != 'noimage.jpg') ? $fileNameToStore : $designData->design_image,
            'desg_2' => $request->input('desg_2'),
            'desg_3' => $request->input('desg_3'),
            'desg_4' => $request->input('desg_4'),
            'desg_5' => $request->input('desg_5'),
            'desg_6' => $request->input('desg_6') 
]);
```

**Alternative Approach**

You can also make two update statements here to keep it clean like this

```
if ($request->hasFile('design_image')) {
        // Get filename with image 
            $filenameWithex=$request->file('design_image');
        // Get just file name
             $filename=$_FILES['design_image']['name'];
            // $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithex,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ex 
            // $extension=pathinfo($filenameWithex,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // File Name To Store
            $fileNameToStore=$filename;
            $path=$request->file('design_image')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);

    design::where('design_no',$id)->update([
            'desg_1' => $request->input('desg_1'),
            'design_image'=> $fileNameToStore,
            'desg_2' => $request->input('desg_2'),
            'desg_3' => $request->input('desg_3'),
            'desg_4' => $request->input('desg_4'),
            'desg_5' => $request->input('desg_5'),
            'desg_6' => $request->input('desg_6') 
     ]);
}else{   // ignore design_image when you don't need to update that
    design::where('design_no',$id)->update([
            'desg_1' => $request->input('desg_1'),
            'desg_2' => $request->input('desg_2'),
            'desg_3' => $request->input('desg_3'),
            'desg_4' => $request->input('desg_4'),
            'desg_5' => $request->input('desg_5'),
            'desg_6' => $request->input('desg_6') 
     ]);
}
```

Comment: sorry for little late ,I used the alternative method which seems suitable for me , but i don't know whether it is the best practices or not if u could explain me

Comment: no prob! well its upto you if you are concerned about line of codes then 1st one is preferable if you are not then 2nd one is suitable for you apparently if you are using if else 2nd one is preferable!